# socket.gethostbyname : conditional statements to catch error codes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to make a portion of an application where the user inputs their domain and the IP addresses is resolved. If socket.gethostbyname doesn't return a result i.e. comes back with **socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known**: I want to loop the input function so as the user is asked to input again until a valid result is returned for resolvedip. I have used while loops and a manner of things but can't seem to get the result I am after.

What would I need to add to the  code below to achieve this ?

```
nsip = input("\nEnter your target website [example: google.com] : ")
resolvedip = socket.gethostbyname(nsip)#
print(resolvedip)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
while True:
    try:
        nsip = input("\nEnter your target website [example: google.com] (q to quit) : ")
        if nsip == "q" or nsip == "quit":
            break
        resolvedip = socket.gethostbyname(nsip)
    except:
        print("Couldn't lookup: "+nsip)
        continue
    print(resolvedip)
```

Result:

```
Enter your target website [example: google.com] (q to quit) : one.one.one.one
1.0.0.1

Enter your target website [example: google.com] (q to quit) : google.com
142.250.74.142

Enter your target website [example: google.com] (q to quit) : haha.store.com
Couldn't lookup: haha.store.com

Enter your target website [example: google.com] (q to quit) : q
PS C:\Python>
```